# its or his in this context?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns, animacy

Which one is correct:

1. A child born today
   inherits a world vastly different from that of **its** parent’s generation.
2. A child born today
   inherits a world vastly different from that of **his** parent’s generation.

I found the first version of the sentence in a book. But my humble knowledge of English language says it must be written **his** instead of **its**.

What do you think and why?

**EDIT:**

The posts given on [Is referring to people as "it" considered rude?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111368/is-referring-to-people-as-it-considered-rude) do not answer my question because all the answers refer to rudeness and anger such as in the accepted one: *this is something that would be said only in the heat of anger*. But the author of the book is not trying to offend anybody.

Comment: [a wise child knows **his** own father](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+wise+child+knows+his+own+father%22) gets an estimated 62 hits in Google Books, but [a wise child knows **its** own father](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+wise+child+knows+its+own+father%22) gets 256. Personally I think avoiding "impersonal, objectfying" ***its*** in such contexts is just a bit prissy - whereas *...knows **his or her** father* is the absolute pits in terms of "political correctness".

Comment: Very interesting feeback. It is really weird to see from your links that ***its*** is more used in this cas.Thank you a lot @FumbleFingers

Comment: I didn't bother looking at the dates (change over time) for those examples, but I wouldn't necessarily assume the *later* ones are more likely to "hypercorrect" contexts like your example. Where exactly one draws the line varies, obviously, but I doubt anyone would entertain, say, *A slave knows its master* except as an outrageously facetious / offensive twisting of natural English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically you can use either, but you may want to choose to just use **his**, **her**, or **his/her**.

If you are referring to any child in general then you can reasonably use the word **its**, although you may prefer to use **the child's** or even better ([for political correctness](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/111369/44824)), **his/her**.

> 1. A child born today inherits a world vastly different from that of **the child's** parent’s generation.
> 2. A child born today inherits a world vastly different from that of **his/her** parent’s generation.

However, if you are referring to a specific baby and you know its sex, for the reasons [@Robusto gave in this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/111369/44824), it may be more politically correct to use the word **his** or **her**.

Comment: Can I ask why the downvote?

Comment: grammatically you can use either.  For political correctness you may choose to just use **his**, **her**, or **his/her**.

Comment: A newly born baby is often referred as "it". Maybe this was what the author meant - today, (almost) literally

Comment: @Rompey - A newborn is still a **he** or **she**.  Babies are not generally born under both sexes although obviously there are exceptions with intersex babies.

Comment: I don't think that the gender of the baby was important to the author of the sentence the PO cited. A newborn was meant, thanks

Comment: @Rompey - Which is why **he/she** would be a suitable alternative.  It is more politically correct than **it**.

Comment: And that's that? Amen!

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer said, "his," "his or her" and "its" are all correct. There are also writers who alternate between "his" and "her" throughout a text.

I'd like to mention another possibility: "*their* parents' generation."

This use of "their" is controversial. It is claimed by its opponents to be incorrect. However, it is widely used by well-educated people who are good writers, at all levels of formality.